# Rewrite Rule for dynamic count of params

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please advice.

I have:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
```

so `/blog/last` transform to `/index.php?page=blog&action=last`

I want keep these rules and plus i'd like to have as follows:

```
/search?p1=1 transform to /index.php?page=search&p1=1

/search?p1=1&unknown_name=unknown_value transform to /index.php?page=search&p1=1&unknown_name=unknown_value
```

etc whatever count of parameters in url ther names and values

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need `QSA` flag to keep existing query strings.
2. In your regex hyphen needs to be at first or last position inside character class to remain unescaped. You can also use `\w` in place of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That is not what i asked at all. "/search?p1=1 transform to /index.php?page=search&p1=1". Thanks for your suggestion but it's not working.

Comment: What exactly did you ask for then. Explain properly. What is problem with `/index.php?page=search&p1=1` URI?

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: No problem. Just in case i found another solution before RewriteRule ^/?([^/][^\./]*)[:;,\.]*$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L], but your one is shorter